# Formatting C-strings

Tags: c++, string

The program is supposed to use a function that accepts a pointer to a C-string as an argument and capitalizes the first character of each sentence in the string. I'm having trouble with the output. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Capitalize(char *);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char sentence[1000];


    cout << "Please enter a sentence: " << endl;
    cin.getline(sentence, 1000);

    char *sentencePtr = sentence;


    Capitalize(sentencePtr);

    cout << sentencePtr;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void Capitalize(char *str){
    int count;

    for(count = 0; count < strlen(str); count++){

        if(str[count] = '.'){

            count += 2;

            toupper(str[count]);

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? Can you please give some example input and output?

Answer (score 2):

```
        toupper(str[count]);
```

This converts the character to upper case and then throws the result away. You want:

```
        str[count]=toupper(str[count]);
```

Also, this is an assignment:

```
    if(str[count] = '.'){
```

You want a comparison:

```
    if(str[count] == '.'){
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good go, but `toupper` *returns* the uppercase version of a character, it does not modify the argument that is provided. Try this:

```
 // note, you must use '==', not '='
 if(str[count] == '.')
 {
        count += 2;
        str[count] = toupper(str[count]);
 }
```

As an exercise, try and avoid using C-strings altogether, and see if you can do it using only the `std::string` class. Ultimately, you will realise that using `std::string` is much easier than using plain old C-strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an assignment operator (=) not a comparison (==), you need to change:

```
if(str[count] = '.'){
```

To:

```
if(str[count] == '.'){
```

As others have indicated, your use of toupper isn't quite right either, as it returns the new value, it doesn't modify the orignal as it doesn't take a reference.

```
str[count] = toupper(str[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
if(str[count] = '.')
```

should be:

```
if(str[count] == '.')
```

Also, `str[count] = toupper(str[count]);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your comparison is wrong. Try changing

```
if(str[count] = '.')
```

to

```
if(str[count] == '.'){
```

remember -> = is a assignment operator
== is a comparison operator

(I think your Capitalize func is wrong, but i dont know if its how you want it to be)